# Android listview empty

Tags: android, android-listview

I am building a news application and I don't want to show main activity with in ListView right away while its still loading, for that I created a splash activity. But now I can't figure it out how to check when the loading is done, but then I got an idea, can I somehow check from splash activity is the ListView from main activity empty or not?

```
public class Init extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.init);

        WebView loader = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loader);
        loader.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Create a splash screen, which invokes the async task. The async task should download the news items. Transfer to the main view and populate the listbox when onPostExecute is called...

I suppose this has the advantage of showing progress (onProgressUpdate and publishProgress) - ie if your looking at multiple sources for data, and has an onPostExecute method which determines when the download is complete...

You can also cancel the async task...

Think that meets your needs...

Comment: iam stock with that for week , and i tryed all possible ways except of what you told me , thnak you :)

Comment: Did this answer your question...? To expand on what I was saying...

Splash screen owns AsyncTask and perhaps shows indeterminate progress..? -> AsyncTask downloads news data in the background while the splashscreen is displayed -> Save downloaded data to DB, perhaps? -> AsyncTask updates splash screen in onProgressUpdate, publishProgress (maybe it has downloaded 1 of n items) -> AsyncTask calls onPostExecute when finished executing the onPostExecute should switch to your main view. Main view loads new data from db, which should be very quick since all data is now local...

Comment: You did answer to my question yes :) writing data inside db and then loading it phew seconds later is useless , can i insted onPostExecute() do this : create an object of main class like MainClass mainclass = new MainClass(); and then pass result of onPostExecute() to method inside mainclass like mainclass.parseXML(result);

Comment: SetExtras on the intent before starting the mainview, and then do getIntent().getextras() in the MainView... in onPostExecute() { this.splashscreen.onDataLoaded(xmlData); } in Splashscreen.onDataLoaded(string xmlData){ Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainView.class); //set extras(xmlData); startActivity(intent); }

Answer (score 0):

Are you also looking for when the page has finished downloading? If so, create a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) subclass, attach it to your WebView, and handle the override onPageFinished().

Comment: yea that will also help me , thnak you ;)